# Can we insert data into tables without entity in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a large amount of data, so can I insert it into the database without creating an Entity class?

Comment: yes, through sql insert statement

Comment: Can you explain why you want to use JPA but don't want to create an Entity class?

Comment: Entity classes are how jpa knows which tables map to your data. So no, jpa without entities isn't an option. If you have a lot of data jdbc may be the wrong choice anyway. Databases have bulk load utilities that are a lot faster.

Comment: If you use `hibernate` with `jpa` it does not make sense to use a different method to manipulate data, otherwise do not use `hibernate`

Answer (score 0):

you can use JdbcTemplate to insert, update, delete and more.

Using Java Config it would be:

```
@Configuration
public class DBConfig {

   @Bean
   public DataSource dataSource() {
      //create a data source
   }

   @Bean
   public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
      return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
   }

   @Bean
   public TransactionManager transactionManager() {
      return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
   }

}
```

you should create a repository that uses JdbcTemplate could be:

```
@Repository
public class JdbcSomeRepository implements SomeRepository {

   private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate ;

   @Autowired
   public JdbcSomeRepository(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
      this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
   } 

   @Override
   @Transactional 
   public int someUpdate(SomeType someValue, SomeOtherType someOtherValue) {
      return jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO SomeTable(column1, column2) VALUES(?,?)", someValue, someOtherValue)
   }
}
```

you can also directly Autowired in the controller.

```
@Autowired
 JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate ;
```

Comment: Spring boot already configures a `JdbcTemplate` and `DataSource` so you don't need that configuration at all.